# Create a 2 levels array in javascript using split

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I need to split a string into a two level array (or rather array inside and array with auto keys).

**Say the string is:**
item 10~item 11~item 12^ item 20~item 21~item 23^

i would like it to be in similar structure
*i know php - hense the structure*

```
array(
 [0]=> array(
   'item 10',
   'item 11',
   'item 12',
 ),
 [1]=> array(
   'item 20',
   'item 21',
   'item 22',
 ),
)
```

so...
**the first split looks like this right?**

```
function createDataArray(xData) {
    xData.split("^");
    --- WHAT DO I DO HERE? ---

}
```

Would appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply doing it like this, to get your desired output.

```js
var str = 'item 10~item 11~item 12^ item 20~item 21~item 23^';

var arr = [];
str.split('^').forEach(function(v) {
  if (v) {
    arr.push(v.trim().split('~'));
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: i ended up using this just becouse its more readble to me personaly. Thanks a lot for the quick response ;) - help in real time

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you can use `split` and [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to come up with your output:

```js
var input = 'item 10~item 11~item 12^ item 20~item 21~item 23^';
var splits = input.split(/\^\s*/).reduce(function(arr, item) {
  if (item.length) {
    arr.push(item.split('~'));
  }
  return arr;
}, []);
console.log(splits);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to do a split, then a map+split:

```
var result = input
  .split('^')                                        // Is an array of strings
  .map(function (str) { return str.split('~'); });   // Is an array of arrays
```

Comment: Note, this does give you an empty array item at the end due to the trailing `^`, and `result[1][0]` has a preceding space. You could cleanup `input` beforehand.

Comment: thanks a lot for your input and the additional information

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example:

```
        function createDataArray(xData) {
            var q = xData.split("^"); //arr of arr
            for (var i in q) {
                q[i] = q[i].split('~');
            }
            console.log(q);
        }
```